# android tab layout with arrow button in tab text

Tags: android

I'm need to make tab to has down arrow beside text.

When I click on the tab, slider open from above.

How to make like this tab layout.

[tab with arrow down btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mNHU.png)

[tab after click on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8VDA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add click listener to tab, and change the tab icon on click, show and hide fragments according to click.

```
 getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
                   tab.setIcon(R.drawable.down_arrow);
        } 
});
```